# How can I fix the discrepancies between Apple crash reporting and my own?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I use a third-party crash reporter for my app, and when I look at the crashes in the web console for it, I see hundreds. However, when I look at the crashes that Apple reports via Xcode, I only see about 30. I realize that I'm getting far fewer crashes from Apple than from the third-party reporter because Apple's system is opt-in, but this seems like far too few crashes. For example, the top crash in Apple has around 6,000 users, which is not *that* far off from that of the top crash in the third-party reporter, so 30 for the total number of crashes in Apple seems way too low.

Answer (score -1):

My intuition is that the Apple crash reporter is probably doing a better job of coalescing multiple related crashes. This is something you could probably verify by looking at some of the crashes in the third-party tool, and seeing whether they're very similar to one of the 30 that Apple gathered.

The "long tail" effect is probably also in play here. Typically, you will have a few "common" crashes, and a lot of "uncommon" crashes. If only 10% of users click the "report" button in the Apple crash dialog, this means your "common" cases will have about 1/10 as many reports in the Apple system. For the "uncommon" cases, you might get ZERO reports, if there were only going to be ten instances total of that crash over a particular period.

Comment: I looked at the crashes of another version and the lowest-ranking crash still had thousands of users